# Div width 100% but want an anchor inside to only be 85px wide?

Tags: css, width

I have a div at 100%, in order to center things
i have an anchor tag inside i only want at 85px width, but it is not recognizing this and will just expand based on the length of text that is in the anchor tag.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="players_names">
    <a class="player_name" href="#">34 J. Langenbrunner</a><br />
    <a class="team_name" href="#">TORONTO</a>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.players_names{
     width: 100%;
     position: relative;
     z-index: 3;
     text-align: center;
 }
.players_names a{
     color: #fff;
 }
.players_names a.player_name {
     width: 85px;
     font-size: 1.1em;
     text-align: center;
     line-height: 1;
 }
```

why can't it just do what i tell it to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, `a` is an inline tag.  In order to specify a width (or height), you will need to get it to render as `inline-block` (or as `block`, since you seem to want it on its own lien anyway):

```
.players_names a.player_name {
     width:85px;
     font-size:1.1em;
     text-align: center;
     line-height: 1;
     display: block;
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

`a` is an inline level tag. Only block level tags can have a width set. As has been stated in the comment by [kmfk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/396318/kmfk), you can set `display: block` in your CSS for the element.

Comment: Which means, you can manually set the anchor tag to display as a block element.  Add `display: block` to your styles.

Answer (score 0):

Just replace

```
players_names a.player_name {
 width: 85px;
 font-size: 1.1em;
 /*text-align: center; - Delete this line */
 margin: 0 auto; /*Add this line*/
 display: block; /*Add this too*/
 line-height: 1;
}
```

Comment: Also, just FYI - a div's default width is 100%, so there's no need to declare it unless you're trying to overwrite a preceding style declaration.

Answer (score 0):

```
display:inline-block;
```

or

```
display:block;
```

to your anchor then you will be able to modify its width and height, and if you want to hide the exceeding content you can use:

```
overflow:hidden;
```

or you can use css3 and warp the word to your width:

```
word-wrap: break-word;
```

hope this helps